# MongoDB $merge with two fields being unique before insert?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have a collection of elements with several fields, including userId and questionId. If I'm in an aggregation pipeline and I have a list of documents that all have userId and questionId as fields, but their values might already be in the collection (ie. a document of

```json
{userId:1, questionId:1, score: 1}
```

but a similar document already exists in the collection

```json
{userId:1, questionId:1, score:0}
```

How do I do a `$merge` into the collection while checking both fields? The $merge function does have an 'on: [field]' field to check overlap, but I don't think it can check two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple fields in the `on` clause using an array.

```js
db.toBe.aggregate([
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "asIs",
      "on": [
        "userId",
        "questionId"
      ],
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wt19VQ-W3VO)